# AccessDenied while using UserPrincipal SetPassword method

Tags: c#, asp.net, access-denied, userprincipal, principalcontext

I am getting an ***AccessDenied*** exception while changing user's password using ***[UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)*** class.

I am logging to an Asp.Net application through **Windows Authentication** *(domain user)*. If I try to change other user's password I am getting the access denied exception. If I am doing the same with user that I am logged in, everything is OK - I can change password.

I thought, that if I will get ***UserPrincipal*** object using ***PrincipalContext***, I will do anything to which my 'Principal - *domain\adminAD*' has privilidges in AD.

Body of method:

```
public bool SetPassword(string userName, string password)
{
    var saved = false;

    var ldapDomainName = "domain";
    var ldapUsersOU = "OU=TEST,DC=domain,DC=com";
    var ldapLogin = "domain\adminAD";
    var ldapPassword = "password";

    try
    {
        using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
           ContextType.Domain,
           ldapDomainName,
           ldapUsersOU,
           ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing | ContextOptions.Negotiate,
           ldapLogin,
           ldapPassword))
        {
            userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
            userPrincipal.SetPassword(password);
            userPrincipal.Save(principalContext);
            saved = true;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // Log exception
     }

     return saved;
  }
```

---

I have already searched for the answer and I know that there are plenty of answers to similar topics. But none of them explain my problem, I guess.

Comment: Since you are using the default, you do not need ContextOptions.  IS it a typo on your SetPassword method call that you have "newPassword" rather than the methods "password"?

Comment: Yes, this is a typo, sorry for that inaccuracy!

Comment: since it appears you are in the same domain, does taking that out of  `var ldapLogin = "domain\adminAD";` make a difference?

Comment: you mean to use `var ldapLogin = "adminAD";` ? If yes, so there is no difference